# Do alarms ever get cancelled on their own?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I create a new alarm with `periodInMinutes` set to a value, does the alarm ever get cancelled on its own?

in my code I set an alarm in the background.js file using `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event.
will the alarm be active and running forever every 60 minutes as long as the extension is installed?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((details) => {
    chrome.alarms.create("alarm", {
        delayInMinutes: 1,
        periodInMinutes: 60
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes, it should persist forever.

Answer (score 0):

The alarm will not be canceled as long as the extension is installed.